# Sudoku Alogirthm does not working as expected

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, sudoku, puzzle

I am trying to get solved sudoku result. But it is not working as I expected.

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],#x0
        [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],#x1
        [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],#x2
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],#x3
        [4, 0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],#x4
        [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],#x5
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],#x6
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],#x7
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]#x8
#       y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8    
    
def possible(x,y,n, matris):
        for i in range(0, 9):
                if matris[x][i] == n:
                        return False
        for i in range(0, 9):
                if matris[i][y] == n:
                        return False
        x0 = (x//3)*3
        y0 = (x//3)*3
        for i in range(0, 3):
                for j in range(0, 3):
                        if matris[x0+i][y0+j] == n:
                                return False
        return True


def solve(sudoku):
        for x in range(9):
                for y in range(9):
                        if sudoku[x][y] == 0: 
                                for n in range(1, 10):
                                        if possible(x, y, n, sudoku):
                                                sudoku[x][y]=n
        return np.matrix(sudoku)
                          
print(solve(grid))
```

The output, as you can see, not giving me the result of the unsolved sudoku grid. I can not see what is the problem.

```
[[5 3 4 2 7 1 0 0 0] 
 [6 7 2 1 9 5 0 0 0] 
 [1 9 8 0 0 0 0 6 0] 
 [8 5 7 0 6 4 1 0 3] 
 [4 8 5 9 0 3 7 0 1] 
 [7 1 0 8 2 0 5 0 6] 
 [3 6 1 0 4 0 2 8 0] 
 [0 0 6 4 1 9 3 0 5] 
 [0 4 0 6 8 0 0 7 9]]
```

What can be the problem , any ideas ?

Comment: You need to backtrack when there are no allowed values for a square. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: how can I apply that to my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the puzzle that you listed in your question has no solution. You can verify it on [Sudoku Solutions](https://www.sudoku-solutions.com/). Click the load button & enter "trincot_for_so" as identification code to load the puzzle.

If in the centre 3x3 box you change the 9 to a 0, then there is a solution. That solution will have an 8 in that cell.

Secondly, your code has a (copy/paste) bug in this line:

```
y0 = (x//3)*3
```

That should be:

```
y0 = (y//3)*3
```

To solve puzzles that *do* have a solution, you'll need to implement backtracking. For that you can use recursion. Your main function would look like this:

```
def solve(sudoku):
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if sudoku[x][y] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(x, y, n, sudoku):
                        sudoku[x][y] = n
                        # Use recursion to solve the rest of the puzzle
                        result = solve(sudoku)
                        # If rest of the puzzle could be solved, return the solution
                        if result is not None:
                            return result
                        # Backtrack. Allow inner loop to try another value
                        sudoku[x][y] = 0
                # If none of the values for this cell work: no solution (None)
                return
    # We only get here when solve was called with a completely filled-in grid
    return np.matrix(sudoku)
```